# How much function will an apple thunderbolt display have on a custom pc?

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I am building a custom PC with an Asus z87 motherboard with thunderbolt connectivity, two GTX 790 graphics cards (when they come out and yes I'm a 3D artist, I will use them).

For my monitors I am looking at daisy-chaining 3 ATD's to my PC.

From research I have gathered that with a bit of effort you can get them to work but it is unclear to me as to whether you will be able to use the speakers, camera, etc.

Also just as a side note also for a possible upgrade in the future would 3 apple retina thunderbolt displays work the same?

Comment: ADT's are apple thunderbolt displays? Or something else?

Comment: iirc pcs using thunderbolt might end up using the internal intel card - so you might not be getting the most out of your graphics cards

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - If I remember a previous response to a question like this, the Thunderbolt controller because it has direct access to the PCI-E channel, the setup should use the GTX 790 cards. The question about the speakers and camera would be left up to driver support, which is unlikely, given they are design for Apple devices. The 3D art programs of course can be setup to use the GTX cards for the rendoring process even if the displays are using the Haswell Intel HD graphic capabilities.

Comment: on the other hand, asus had a passthrough system for thunderbolt that used a discrete card - my desktop has a header, but the system was never released cause it didn't use intel's graphics card. If I was 100% sure, I'd post it as an answer ;p

Comment: Ok, so to confirm ATD's are Apple Thunderbolt Displays. The 3D art program I would be using is Blender and maybe 3DS Max in the future. With the camera and the speakers, I have heard some say that you can modify the settings to use usb out for at least the speakers (don't know about camera). Its not a huge issue if they don't work, its would just be nice if they did. Thanks for the response so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but you can follow [these instructions to get drivers from Apple's BootCamp driver installation](https://duntuk.com/how-install-apple-thunderbolt-display-non-apple-thunderbolt-pc-brightness-control-support).

I've summarized the installation instructions here:

1. Download [Boot Camp 5](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638?locale=en_US)
2. Extract the ZIP file
3. Start a command prompt with admin privileges
4. Change into the drivers directory of the installation package (where `c:\drivers` is the location to which you extracted the ZIP archive):
5. `cd C:\drivers\BootCamp5.0.5033\BootCamp\Drivers\Apple`
6. Install with `msiexec`:
7. `msiexec /i BootCamp.msi`

According to comments in the linked article, webcam and speakers do work.